# How can I disable sublime completing string literals and keep auto-indent

Tags: sublimetext3, auto-indent

Whenever I type `'` in sublime it adds the terminating quote `'` and places the cursor in the middle like this: `'|'`

Same goes for `"` that gets expanded into `"|"`.

This is unwanted behavior for me, the only way I found to turn it off is by setting:

```
"auto_indent": false,
```

However, this makes it cumbersome to write indented code.

Is there anyway to get Sublime to not complete string literals and keep `auto_indent`?

I tested this on Sublime 3 Build 3114 on Windows and Sublime 3 Build 3083 on Linux.

Comment: The setting should be `auto_match_enabled`

Comment: Hi. Seems to work. Was driving me nuts. Thanks. Make this into an answer and I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the setting should be `auto_match_enabled` as you see in definition in the default keybindings:

```js
// Auto-pair quotes
{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\"$0\""}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|\\}|>|$)", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "[\"a-zA-Z0-9_]$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.double - punctuation.definition.string.end", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```